# XCode 4 / iOS 4.3 Build Errors on ASI HTTP Library

Tags: ios, ios4, asihttprequest

My development machine died and I've had to rebuild it from scratch.  I reinstalled the latest XCode which came with iOS SDK 4.3.  I reopened my project and have had to readd all my frameworks to get the code to mostly compile.  I'm down to two errors, both basically this:

error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier'

This is on the file: ASIHTTPRequest.h on these lines:

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE && __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_4_0
BOOL shouldContinueWhenAppEntersBackground;
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier backgroundTask;
#endif
```

which is part of the ASI HTTP library.

I'm targeting iOS 3.2.2 and building on the latest iOS 4.3.  This did not happen in my old environment which was XCode 4 using iOS 4.2.   I have tried using a bunch of different build settings but none have fixed the issue.  Commenting out the lines causes a number of other issues, and that is not a good solution anyways.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my "fix" for this problem was to create a new project in the new XCode version and copy my classes and resources over. It took about a half an hour to do so as I had about 100 files to move, but it worked on the first attempt.

I can only guess that there was some subtle difference between XCode versions I wasn't aware of.  XCode certainly didn't provide any kind of meaningful error message to guide me to it in any event.